# Webscrape with beautiful soup, attribute error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

URL: https://www.mecca.com/en-au/skincare/

I'm trying to scrape each Product's Brand, Name and Ingredient list from the above URL page

My code is able to find the links of each product:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mecca.com/en-au/skincare/"

productlinks = []

for x in range(1,5):
    #r = requests.get
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f'https://www.mecca.com/en-au/skincare/?page={x}').content, "html.parser")
    products = soup.find_all('div', class_="css-1r7iqog")

    for item in products:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            productlinks.append(url + link['href'])
    print(productlinks)
```

However I'm having some trouble getting the Brand, Name and Ingredient list. With no results generated:

```
for link in productlinks:
        response = requests.get(link)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        brand = soup.find("span", class_="css-738lkl e11u5ot719")
        name = soup.find('span', class_='product-name css-x4jxi0 e11u5ot718')
        Ingred = soup.find('p', class_='css-pdiqc3 e151354a4')
```

I've tried tweaking a few things including the below which generated an AttributeError:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

even though there is ingredient text to be scrapped:

```
ingredients = []

for productlink in productlinks:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(productlink).content, "html.parser")
    ingredient_list = soup.find('p', class_="css-pdiqc3 e151354a4")
    ingredients.append(ingredient_list.text)
```

I've read through some of the posts and can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong..
Would be grateful for any help! Thank you in advance

Comment: If you're getting that error, it means that `find()` didn't find what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is with the base URL being used. Originally, it was defined as "https://www.mecca.com/en-au/skincare/", but the correct one is simply "https://www.mecca.com". Due to this discrepancy, the request response = request.get(link) isn’t executed properly, resulting in a 404 error.

I detected this problem using breakpoints in the code, which allowed me to pinpoint the exact point where the error was occurring. It's highly recommended to always check that the responses from requests return a 200 status code, ensuring that the request has been successful. This is a practice I've adopted throughout my work experience and it has proven to be very useful.

Additionally, I corrected the selector used to obtain the brand, as it wasn't retrieving any value. I also adjusted the code to extract the text for each of the values you want to obtain.

Here's the corrected code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mecca.com"

productlinks = []

for x in range(1,5):
    #r = requests.get
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f'https://www.mecca.com/en-au/skincare/?page={x}').content, "html.parser")
    products = soup.find_all('div', class_="css-1r7iqog")

    for item in products:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            productlinks.append(url + link['href'])
    # print(productlinks)

for link in productlinks:
    response = requests.get(link)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    brand = soup.find("span", class_="product-brand css-738lkl e11u5ot719").string
    name = soup.find('span', class_='product-name css-x4jxi0 e11u5ot718').string
    Ingred = soup.find('p', class_='css-pdiqc3 e151354a4').string

    print(brand)
    print(name)
    print(Ingred)
```

Comment: Hi Martijn, thank you so much. Really appreciate your help, I'm still a beginner so thank you for taking the time look through my code